# "supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target" in angular as the code is given below

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-httpclient

As I am going through HTTP and Observables I've encountered the problem indicating the supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. The code is as given below.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { Http } from '@angular/http';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import { IEmployee } from './employee';


    @Injectable()

    export class EmployeeService {

      private _url: string = "/assets/data/employees.json";

      constructor(private http:Http) { }

      getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]>{

        return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);

      }

    }
```

The error occurs at the line

```
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url);
```

the json data is in the path located by " _url " string. 
Also I had created the interface named " IEmployee " inside "employee.ts"

employee.ts

```
   export interface IEmployee {
        id: number,
        name: string,
        age: number
    }
```

the versions I'm using is as below

```
    angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
    node: 8.11.1
    os: win32 x64
    @angular/common: 2.4.10
    @angular/compiler: 2.4.10
    @angular/core: 2.4.10
    @angular/forms: 2.4.10
    @angular/http: 2.4.10
    @angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
    @angular/router: 3.4.10
    @angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

all other seems right. I need help here thank you.

I used it in a component called " employee-list" and there I want to show the employee list.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'employee-list',
      template: `
        <h2> Employee List</h2>
        <ul *ngFor = " let employee of employees " >
          <li> {{ employee.name }} </li>
        </ul>
      `,
       styles: []
    })

    export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
      public employees = [];
      constructor( private _employeeService: EmployeeService ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this._employeeService.getEmployees()
        .subscribe(data => this.employees = data);
      }

    }
```

Comment: Please also provide HTML from where you are calling the function

Comment: I've added the part you asked in the question now.

Comment: you're using `angular 2.x` version with old `HttpModule` which i don't think supports generic http methods overloads like `http.get<someType>`. not 100% but that's what i'd first check in docs.

Comment: @deezg thanks mate. I updated my angular version. Now it works fine

Comment: glad it worked!;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
search(term: string): Observable<SearchItem[]> {
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?term=${term}&media=music&limit=20`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
        .map(res => {
          return res.json().results.map(item => {
            return new SearchItem(
                item.trackName,
                item.artistName,
                item.trackViewUrl,
                item.artworkUrl30,
                item.artistId
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

Change your data accordingly

Comment: I updated my angular version and it worked fine. Thank you for your consideration.